# XAMPP PHP not showing new files added

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

doing a school projectwith xampp and php. we got a base website that we have to edit and add features too. but when i add a page with a link to it, it loads the page as blank or doesnt load at all. for example: there is a menu with links to the different pages in. one of them is register. when you click on register. it does change from healthone.localhost to healthone.localhost/register in the browser . but the page does not actually change. it stays on the home page. same happens with newly added pictures. it does load the other already there pictures. but if i change them to something else that new picture doea not load

Comment: what is it you add? css and js file?

Comment: You need to check PHP (pointed by error_log directive in php.ini file) and Apache logs (under logs directory)

Comment: no i mean like any changes made do not load. so adding a file or changing a picture. whatever is new doesnt load.

Comment: Either you're not editing the right file, or not saving it properly, or maybe the browser just cached your old version. First step is to try Ctrl+F5 in the browser when you're on that page, to force it to reload everything from the server (rather than its cache)